# Andengine Anchor Center: Screen Capture is flipped vertically

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine

I am using the Anchor Center branch of Andengine GLES2. When I make a screen capture, the file it saves has the image flipped vertically. Does anyone know how to either fix this, or how to flip a bitmap vertically?

I am assuming this is because in this branch the origin point (0,0) is at the bottom left, rather than the top left.

Under the hood it is using GL20.drawPixels(), if that helps any.

Thanks for your help, in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620325/screen-capture-in-andengine-gives-upside-down-mirror-image/